# Big application, 300-400 textbox controls, forbid unicode input for all textboxes - How can It fast?

Tags: winforms

I have a big application with many textbox controls (about 300-400).

I need to forbid an unicode input for all the textboxes. **Is there any easy way to do that** ?

C#, VS 2008, .NET 2.0

---

Maybe there's some global application handler or something else ?

**Edit**: I want to allow an input of latin alphabet symbols and digits. Chinese, japanese, and other alphabets must be prohibited.

Comment: How do you define "an unicode"? Every character in .Net is stored as unicode (UTF-16).

Comment: i want to allow an input of latin alphabet symbols and digits. Unicode is chinese, japanese symbols and other not latin symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom control that encapsulates the TextBox, or simpler a class that inherits from TextBox, and in either case suppress the characters you don't want.  Replace all instances of System.Windows.Forms.TextBox (and TextBox if there are any) with YourCustomClassName.

Comment: Yes, it's a solution. But there are many textboxes and only 1 programmer (me). It'll take much time. Maybe I can it faster ?

Comment: Faster? The whole process will take less than ten minutes. You just do a search and replace after creating your custom control.

Comment: danbystrom, did you do some kind of it before ?

Comment: @nik: Yes, it is common practice. :-)

Comment: @danbystrom, ohh no, i'll try your advice :)